# Difference between cout set_precision(5) + fixed and printf("%lf.5",var)

Tags: c++, printf

I tried to solve the Area problem http://www.infoarena.ro/problema/aria, but with the first code i receive Time Limit Exceeded while with the second everything works fine.
So, what is the difference between these two?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#define max 1000000
using namespace std;

ifstream fin("aria.in");
ofstream fout("aria.out");

int N;
vector< pair<double,double> > points;

double tri_area(pair<double, double> p1, pair<double,double> p2){

    return p1.first * p2.second - p2.first * p1.second;
}

double find_area(){
    double area = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N-1; i++){
        area += tri_area(points[i],points[i+1]);
    }
    area += tri_area(points[N-1], points[0]);
    return abs(area)/2;
}

int main(){
    fin >> N;
    double x, y;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        fin >> x >> y;
        points.push_back(make_pair(x,y));
    }
    fout << std::setprecision(5) << std::fixed << find_area() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

SECOND:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#define max 1000000
using namespace std;

int N;
vector< pair<double,double> > points;

double tri_area(pair<double, double> p1, pair<double,double> p2){

    return p1.first * p2.second - p2.first * p1.second;
}

double find_area(){
    double area = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N-1; i++){
        area += tri_area(points[i],points[i+1]);
    }
    area += tri_area(points[N-1], points[0]);
    return abs(area/2.);
}

int main(){
    freopen("aria.in","r",stdin);
    freopen("aria.out","w",stdout);
    scanf("%d",&N);
    double x, y;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        scanf("%lf %lf",&x,&y);
        points.push_back(make_pair(x,y));
    }
    printf("%lf", find_area());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is telling you time limit is exceeded? Have you checked that the second version is actually giving you the correct answer, and not just an answer?

Comment: I submitted the problem on the site and the evaluation board tells me that the first one is slower than the second. But both are correct :)

Answer (score 0):

The main difference of these versions is

> fin >> x >> y;

and

> scanf("%lf %lf",&x,&y);

but not `fstream` vs `printf` that called ones from the end of program.

The difference is that C++-streams are synchronized with C-streams and this is reduces their speed. If you know, that you'll never mix `fstream` and `FILE*` in your program, you can switch off this synchronization by calling [sync_with_stdio](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) like this:

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
```